# Why the full page update when i change a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi I have a react app and this is my code :

```
this.state = {
  bars: [{
    tom1: Array(16).fill('0'),
  }],
}
tom1Click= (i, j) => {
  let bar = this.state.bars.slice();
  if(bar[i].tom1[j] === '1'){
    bar[i].tom1[j] = '0';
  }
  else
    bar[i].tom1[j] = '1';
  this.setState({bars: bar})
}
```

I have 16 component of Tom in my page and I want when one of them clicked that state value change to 0 or 1 but when I click on one of the Toms the whole state updated and whole page reRendered
what should I do to handle this, and when I click on component just that component reRender

Comment: Use `shouldComponentUpdate()` ?

Comment: this is why i prefer using angular.....`setState()` will affect your application state and afterwards the `render()` method will be called - if you have a lot of state changes in your app and you do not take massivley care to your code style your `render()` methods will be called very often.

Comment: @RedaMeskali no I didn't use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to make this work is to have 2 components a parent one that will render 16 child component, the child component will have a boolean state and a click handler that will have a simple line of code `setState({bar:!this.state.bar});` for example. Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to use the bar state in another part of my code and I need it I lifted up the state and here it is , also handler and state passed as props to the child component

Comment: what part of your code ? if it's another child component then it will be easy to just pass it as props to the child, if not then you will need to pass them using a method from the child component to the other component passing by the parent but this will be a little awkward if your app is too large, if it is the case the best thing to do then is to use a state management system like React context api or Redux.